# Simplify formula that checks student year level and mark to a letter grade

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am writing a Google Sheet that checks a student's year level, then assigns a letter grade based on their mark in an assessment. If there is no mark, it is designed to leave the cell blank.

The following formula is successful if a bit clunky. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

`=IF(COUNTBLANK(AA12)>=1,"",IFS(P12=5,(IF(AA12>32,"A", (IF(AA12>28,"B",(IF(AA12>19, "C", (IF(AA12>16, "D", "E")))))))),P12=6,(IF(AA12>37,"A", (IF(AA12>32,"B",(IF(AA12>24, "C", (IF(AA12>19, "D", "E")))))))),P12=4,(IF(AA12>28,"A", (IF(AA12>24,"B",(IF(AA12>16, "C", (IF(AA12>12, "D", "E")))))))),P12=3,(IF(AA12>23,"A", (IF(AA12>19,"B",(IF(AA12>12, "C", (IF(AA12>8, "D", "E"))))))))))`

The students' grades are stored in Column 'P', and their marks are in Column "AA"

Answer (score 0):

[link to my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tFz7ZJyMWmwb3WctRdW-ZpwPfD5ag-hcOgbp0J2aas4/edit?usp=sharing).

I basically used `VLOOKUP` on its true state. According to the [Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en):

> If `is_sorted` is `TRUE` or omitted, the nearest match (less than or equal to the search key) is returned. If all values in the search column are greater than the search key, #N/A is returned.

So we have 4 lookup tables, one for each grade. I used named ranges to reference each easily. I had to add one to each grade since `VLOOKUP` will look for less than or equal, while your formula only less than. Easy enough fix.

Each lookup table also has to be sorted (lowest to highest). This is important. You might as well just copy and paste my Data spreadsheet onto yours to keep it consistent.

The main formula uses just uses `SWITCH` to differentiate between grades.
You're going to need to adjust the references a bit, but that's simple enough. Here's an adjusted formula:

```
=SWITCH(
    P12,
    3,
    VLOOKUP(
        AA12,
        grade3LookUp,
        2
    ),
    4,
    VLOOKUP(
        AA12,
        grade4LookUp,
        2
    ),
    5,
    VLOOKUP(
        AA12,
        grade5LookUp,
        2
    ),
    6,
    VLOOKUP(
        AA12,
        grade6LookUp,
        2
    )
)
```

It's a bit more work, but it's definitely much simpler and easier to maintain. Also easier to apply to other grades.

P.S. My sheet has a button on the right. It so that I can easily trigger the random function and see if it's behaving correctly. Thought I should clarify.

Answer (score 0):

##### Formula in `AB2`

```
=MAP(P2:P, AA2:AA,
   LAMBDA(g, m, IFERROR(
     INDEX(letters, XMATCH(m-1, INDEX(cutoff,,MATCH(g,grades,0)), -1, 1))
   ))
)
```

#### Named Ranges

*<sup>I use named ranges to make formulas shorter and easier to read.</sup>*

| Name | Range | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| letters | A2:A6 | List of possible letters (A-E) |
| cutoff | B2:E6 | Table of mark cutoffs for each letter |
| grades | B1:E1 | List of students' grade levels (grade 3, grade 4, etc.) |

[image]

#### Formula Notes

```
1 |  =MAP(P2:P, AA2:AA, LAMBDA(g, m, 
2 |     IFERROR(
3 |       INDEX(letters, 
4 |             XMATCH(m-1, 
5 |                    INDEX(cutoff,,MATCH(g,grades,0)), 
6 |                    -1, 1)))))
```

| Line | Notes |
| --- | --- |
| #1 | **MAP** all students' data into a single **LAMBDA** formula `MAP(P2:P, AA2:AA, LAMBDA(g, m,` **Grades** `P2:P` mapped to variable `g` **Marks** `AA2:AA` mapped to variable `m` |
| #2 | Wrap formula in **IFERROR** to deal with missing values and empty rows. |
| #3 - 6 | Use **INDEX** to identify the correct letter `INDEX(reference, [row], [column])` **reference** = `letters` **[row]** = `XMATCH(m-1,INDEX(cutoff,,MATCH(g,grades,0)),-1,1)` **[column]** is skipped as unnecessary, but could be `1` |
| #4 - 6 | Use **XMATCH** to identify the **[row]** <sup>`XMATCH(search_key, lookup_range, [match_mode], [search_mode])`</sup> **search_key** = `m-1` (mapped mark from `AA2:AA`) <sup>*subtract 1 because* **mark** *can't =* `cutoff`</sup> **lookup_range** = `INDEX(cutoff,,MATCH(g,grades,0))` <sup>*more detail on* line #5 *notes*</sup> **[match_mode]** = `-1` <sup>*exact match or the next value lower than* **search_key**</sup> **[search_mode]** = n/a <sup>*Default* `1`, *search first to last*</sup> |
| #5 | **lookup_range** = `INDEX(reference, [row], [column])` <sup>Use **INDEX** to find the column of `cutoff` whose heading (***grade***) matches `g` (grade from`P2:P`)</sup> `INDEX(cutoff,,MATCH(g,grades,0))` **reference** = `cutoff` **[row]** = n/a **[column]** = `MATCH(g,grades,0)` <sup>**MATCH** *student's grade* `g` *to the* **grades** *headings*, **[match mode]** = `0` *exact match*</sup> |